# R- tables package - error subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, formatting

I need to create a fancy table and export it as png. I'm trying tables package in R. I need to group "variacion" by groups of agents ("agentes") who had a positive variation vs the rest. I want the mean, sd and the number of agents who fulfill these conditions

My table is:

```
  agente mes1 mes2   variacion
1     a1 0.50 0.60  0.20000000
2     a2 0.70 0.65 -0.07142857
3     a3 0.60 0.75  0.25000000
4     a4 0.80 0.60 -0.25000000
5     a5 0.78 0.90  0.15384615
```

My output should be (including format):

[image]

You can arrive to those numbers by doing for example:

```
sd(t_agentes1$variacion[t_agentes1$variacion<=0])
```

And the result is the last number in the table for the column sd: 0.126

So in tables library:

```
library(tables)
X<-t_agentes1$variacion

latex( tabular( (X > 0) + (X < 0) + 1
                  + ~ ((n = 1) + X*(mean + sd + length)) ) )
```

But I get the error:

> non-numeric argument to binary operator

Also when I try the first example of the package I get the same error

> tabular( (Species + 1) ~ (n=1) + Format(digits=2)*
>       +              + (Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width)*(mean + sd), data=iris )
>       Error in e[[3]] : subscript out of bounds

I really don't understand the parameters of this package. Is there a way to do the grouping? I'm really lost with this so any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Well, it would probably help if you avoided simple syntax errors like `*+` or `*++` which are present in two of your failed attempts. But more broadly, I can't understand at all what sort of table you're trying to make in the first place. Perhaps you could describe it more clearly in words?

Comment: "I need to group by month " -> which one is the month variable?

Comment: Hi @Ricky, thanks. I pasted the table I need and explained better.

Comment: Have you been through the [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/vignettes/tables.pdf)? there are a lot of useful examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
X <- read.table(header = TRUE, text="agente mes1 mes2   variacion
1     a1 0.50 0.60  0.20000000
2     a2 0.70 0.65 -0.07142857
3     a3 0.60 0.75  0.25000000
4     a4 0.80 0.60 -0.25000000
5     a5 0.78 0.90  0.15384615")

X <- within(X, variation <- factor(variacion > 0, levels = c(TRUE, FALSE),
                                   labels = c('variation > 0',
                                              'variation <= 0')))
library(tables)
# latex(
#   tabular(Heading() * variation ~ 
#             Justify(l) * (Heading() * Format(digits = 2) * variacion * (mean + sd) + (number = (n = 1))),
#           data = X))

latex(
  tabular(Heading() * variation ~ 
            Justify(l) * (Heading() * variacion * (Format(digits = 2) * mean + Format(digits = 2) *sd) + (number = (n = 1))),
          data = X))

#                     mean  sd     number
# variation $>$ 0     0.20  0.048  3     
# variation $\\leq$ 0 -0.16 0.126  2
```

Gives me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without prettifying the results:

```
tabular((X > 0) + (X < 0) ~ mean*X + sd*X + length*X)
```